# How to say "I grew up thinking about X"?

Tags: english-to-japanese

The context is simple, in a speech, I am talking about how I grew up with Japan on my mind.

I am familiar with `について` and `と思います`, yet i am not entirely sure about the usage here. In English, I'd say the following:

> I grew up
>
> I am thinking about Japan

The Japanese translation of the two would be:

> 私は育ちました
>
> 私は日本のことを思っています

Correct? Now what grammar is used to connect the two?

Comment: Could you maybe give a complete sentence meaning "I grew up thinking about X" using について and/or と思います?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I think he meant that he is aware of those two expressions but he isn't sure about using them in a sentence.

Comment: @strawberryjam Oh, I thought she meant that she can use those two expressions, but is not sure they are fit for this particular context...

Comment: @Earthliŋ strawberryjam is correct here. I am aware of the two expressions but do not know how to use them in this situation, if these are the correct ones to use at all

Comment: What comes to mind is something like ”日本のことがいつも心の中にあるのとして育った”, but I am not sure it is the natural way of saying it.

Comment: @kijo you can still try to fill in the rest of the sentence. Do you know how to say "grow up"? Do you know how to say "I"? Do you know how to say "X"? What is "X"?

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga I have edited my description to what I think is clearer now. I do know how to say the two sentences by their own, yet not when put together in a single sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you connect the two sentence like 私は育ちました and 私は日本のことを思っています, you can say 私は日本のことを(いつも or 常に)思いながら育ちました.

You can use "～ながら", it means "with" and "while".

Comment: You really saved my skin, thank you greatly!